# Issues on bootstrap typeahead

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Can we bypass on apostrophe on typeahead?

I have the following data which I brought from database in array:

"31-Apple","53-Apple","58-Banana", "98-Lady's Finger"

but the display is

[image]

whereas I need is

[image]

with (')
How can I manage to get the solution?

```
<?php $list=NULL;
    $getcom=mysql_query("select * from tblcommodity order by commodityname");
    while($setcom=mysql_fetch_array($getcom))
    {
        if($list==NULL)
        {
            $comma="";
        }
        else
        {
            $comma=",";
        }
        $list.=$comma."\"".$setcom['commodityid']."-".$setcom['commodityname']."\"";
    }
?>
<input type="text" class="span3" autocomplete="off" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='[<?php echo $list ?>]' name="CommodityID">
```

Comment: show us php and mysql code to fetch the result

Comment: is that so necessary?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#id').typeahead({
   name: 'Author',
   local: ['12-BalaGuruSwamy', '11-Forouzan', '10-Wayne Tomasi', '9-William Stallings', '8-John C Martin', '7-Robert Lusier']
});
```

You should pass the database response into the local like the above, you can achieve the functionality you need..

Comment: what bout if name is O'Briens

Comment: You can use like this " O\'Briens "

Comment: i did but got no solution